# Is there an alternative (more poetic term) to avoid making the choice between "simpler" and "more simple"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to translate a Greek essay in English. Let me give you the text above and below the word "*simpler*":

> Actually the first, more systematic - and most effective -
>   propagandists were, since the dawn of time, the founders, preachers
>   and apologists of religion. Their work was arduous and complex. It
>   required creativity, almost sophistic ingenuity, imagination and
>   unsurpassable persuasion. Because it is much easier to propagate and
>   spread an ideology than a quite complex, and in many occasions cruelly
>   harsh, religious faith. **It is simpler** to create a positive image for a
>   sovereign or political leader than to convince billions of people that
>   an invisible (but almighty and most merciful) Father exists.

The word "simpler" at that particular spot does not sound good to me. Is there an alternative that I could use?

P.S: please let me know of any other mistakes that you may have noticed in my translation (:

P.P.S: Since someone asked for the Greek version. Essay Source:

http://www.ndimou.gr/articledisplay.asp?cat_parent=2&time_id=70&cat_id=2

Comment: Would "easier" sound any better to you?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, or unpoetic, about *simpler* in your sentence. I suppose you could go with something like, "It is less difficult to create..." or "It takes less effort to create..."

Comment: Seeing that you used "easy" in the sentence before, I was going to suggest something like "less demanding/challenging", too.

Comment: You can’t say *more simple* there. It has to be *simpler*.

Comment: Could you provide Greek version?

Comment: @Carlo_R. edited post to include the Greek version.

Comment: I suggest asking your question on [writers.stackexchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com) because the translation has numerous problems more important than replacing that word.

Comment: @jwpat7 can you please give me an example?

Comment: The first sentence is ambiguous and ungrammatical.  Is "the first" the subject, or part of an appositive?  *Their* in next sentence is ambiguous.  *creativity, almost sophistic ingenuity* and *quite complex, and in many occasions cruelly harsh* both are clumsy, totally unpoetic; *in* is incorrect preposition; etc.  You could delete the question here and repost in writers.stackexchange for fuller comments; I suggest only linking to the Greek text there, rather than inlining it.

Comment: @jwpat7 thanks a lot for your notes. I will probably ask in writers.stackexchange when I have a final draft of the translation. For now, I just need an alternative to the word "simpler" in this context. 
P.S: I followed your advice and removed the Greek text (leaving only the link).

Comment: @jwpat7 - Yes, the sentence is ungrammatical, but the question is clear: F1234k is searching for an 'unusual' synonym of _more simple_

Comment: Also, just as a side thought - I'm not sure the word is the source of the non-poeticness, I think it's more the bits following feel a bit hard to parse? For example, you could probably strike 'or political leader' and pull out the brackets and convert the last bit to a list which might improve the feel..(i.e.: *It is simpler to create a positive image for a sovereign than to convince billions of people that an invisible, almighty, and most merciful, Father exists*)

Comment: Off-topic. This is essentially "please help with my translation".

Comment: @tanantish Did you really just say *non-poeticness*? Ug. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a rewrite as follows, if you aren't trying to adhere too strictly to any specific form or voice:

"One can more readily create a positive image... than convince billions..."

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading the statement as you wanting to say "A is a lot simpler than B" and that you're doing so by emphasizing the relative natures of the two tasks (living, breathing, actual politician with earthly powers, vs invisible entity with almighty, unimaginable abilities). If you're doing that, perhaps another approach that might sound more poetic is to exaggerate one side of the equation:

> Creating a positive image for a sovereign or political leader is *trivial* when compared to the challenge of convincing billions of people that an invisible (but almighty and most merciful) Father exists.

or as a direct substitution (but it just sounds a bit forced to my ear..):

> It is *comparatively trivial* to create a positive image for a sovereign or political leader than to convince billions of people that an invisible (but almighty and most merciful) Father exists.